# How to parse li from html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, parsing, google-chrome-extension

Let's assume that I want to create an extension that parses the twitter account.
My manifest.json is;

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Twitter",
"description": "Stackoverflow",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
"permissions": [
  "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
 ]
}
```

My popup.js is;

```
function httpGet(theUrl, callback){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true );
  xmlhttp.send();
}

window.onload = function(){
  httpGet("https://twitter.com/StackCareers",function(result) {
    var el = document.createElement('html');
    el.innerHTML = result;
    console.log(el.querySelector('.js-stream-item stream-item stream-item'));
   });
}
```

I want to get the li objects as a list which have class of `js-stream-item stream-item stream-item` Or how can I parse `<ol>` which have class`stream-items js-navigable-stream`

Why `el.getelementsbyclassname` does not work? How can get li objects as a list?

Comment: You are using ID selector(`#`)

Comment: My mistake I edit as (`.`) but now I get null

Comment: Valid selector: `el.querySelector('.js-stream-item.stream-item.stream-item')`

Comment: @Rayon but it as; `el.querySelector(".js-tweet-text-container>p").innerText ` but this returns only 1 tweet. I want them as a list.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and `loop` it!

Comment: @Rayon actually this is what I'm asking, I don't know how to get them as a list. How can I `loop` by using `querySelector`?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will select `array-like` object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `querySelectorAll` to select elements and Use `Array.from` to cast/convert `array-like-object` to array to use `Array#` methods.

```js
function httpGet(theUrl, callback) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

window.onload = function() {
  httpGet("https://twitter.com/StackCareers", function(result) {
    var el = document.createElement('html');
    el.innerHTML = result;
    var allLiElems = el.querySelectorAll(".stream-items.js-navigable-stream li p");
    Array.from(allLiElems).forEach(function(elem) {
      console.log(elem.textContent);
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use queryselector as follows :

```
var all=document.querySelector("ul>li.js-stream-item.stream-item");
```

This says : paint all li elements inside a ul tag with classes js-stream-item and stream-item.

Comment: This results as null, but maybe I'm mistaken?